# UWP Root frame vs Page frame

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Here is typical App.xaml.cs code

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
#if DEBUG
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            //this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
        }
#endif
        rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
            rootFrame.Navigated += OnNavigated;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;

            // Register a handler for BackRequested events and set the
            // visibility of the Back button
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;

            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
                rootFrame.CanGoBack ?
                AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible :
                AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
        }

        if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
        {
            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                // parameter
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SignInPage), e.Arguments);
            }
            // Ensure the current window is active
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
    }
```

When `rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SignInPage), e.Arguments);`is called, `SignInPage` is created. In `SignInPage.xaml.cs`, there might be code like: `this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(FramePage));`. Is the `Frame` from `this.Frame.` the same as `rootFrame`? If it is, when and where does the `Page` class get assigned the root frame from `App.xaml.cs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is the same `Frame` object, as the `Page` has a reference to the frame controlling it's content. In other words the `Frame` that did the navigation to the page.

> **Frame**
>
> Gets the *controlling* Frame for the Page content.

Source: [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page)

This property is automatically set on navigation and is first available in your `Page` object in the `OnNavigatedTo` method.